# How to add an AND condition to SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add an AND condition where `active = true` is also incorporated within an SQL query inside of rails.

`Schema.rb`

```
...
create_table 'relationships', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  'follower_id'
    t.integer  'followed_id'
    t.datetime 'created_at',                 null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at',                 null: false
    t.boolean  'active', default: true
    t.index ['followed_id'], name: 'index_relationships_on_followed_id'
    t.index %w[follower_id followed_id], name: 'index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id', unique: true
    t.index ['follower_id'], name: 'index_relationships_on_follower_id'
  end
...
```

`user.rb`

```
...
def feed
 following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                  WHERE follower_id = :user_id AND active = true"
                     
  View.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
         OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id).includes(:user)
 end
...
```

However the addition of `AND active = TRUE` does not seem to work to pull `followed_ids` with `follower_id` as `self` and where the `active` boolean is `true`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to solve it by assigning an `active` within the query.

```
...
def feed
 following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                  WHERE follower_id = :user_id AND active = :active"
                     
  View.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
         OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id, active: true).includes(:user)
 end
...
```